# Chrome told 'Invaild Group' using Regex to format number

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to turn number like "123456" into "123,456".
My original code is

`number.replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',')`

It works fine when the size of number isn't a multiple of three.

So I tried to add `(?<=\d)` to make sure the comma wouldn't be added at the begin.But chrome said it's a invalid regular expression

`number.replace(/(?=(?<=\d)(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',')`

So what is the correct expression to format the number?

**UPDATE ：**

Solved the comma's issue.

But still I don't understand why the expression would throw error.Those brackets are paired.

`var number = "123456";
number = number.replace(/(?=(?<=\d)(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',')`
`

Comment: a single example wouldn't be enough . Post some more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + c : c;
});
```

Reference: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)